# How to deal with /usr/sbin and /usr/local/sbin in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to use a system service in my shell, but the bin path of that service is different in different machines (/usr/sbin/myservice or /usr/local/sbin/myservice).

So, how can I write a shell which can work on every machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use

```
/usr/bin/env myservice
```

or even

```
myservice
```

Which will search the path for the first occurrence of `myserivce`.

Answer (score 0):

If they are in `$PATH`, you don't have to specify the full path.

Or, you may have to test multiple possible path, and use first available.